# Replacing characters in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have one noumber in my input xml file like this **19778.40** but I want to change to **19778,40**(comma instead of dot) in my output xml file through xslt.

How can I format this number? I don't want to use any templates for it.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the translate() function. As an illustration, this XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="the-number" select="*/text()" />  
The input number with European formatting is <xsl:value-of select="translate($the-number,'.',',')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...will transform this input...

```
<t>19778.40</t>
```

...into this...

```
The input number with European formatting is 19778,40
```

---

**OR**

use the format-number() function like so...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:decimal-format name="euro" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="." />

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="the-number" select="*/text()" />  
The input number with European formatting is <xsl:value-of select="format-number($the-number,'#,00','euro')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 for the `format-number()`. Using `translate()` is the less favorable approach.

Comment: @Kundan, As pointed by Tomalak, the recommended solution, which is more generic and powerful, is to use the `format-number()` function.